# Dividing using vectors, but

Tags: prometheus, promql, victoriametrics

I am dividing two queries to find a percentage data. Sometimes the query in the numerator receives any data, because the value doesn't exist. But when I divide by the other query it still retrieves data as 1's.

```
(count(job{branch="qa", status="failed", project_id="123"}) OR vector(0))/(count(job{branch="qa", status="success", project_id="123"})OR vector(1))
```

I have tried to use a function called Absent. Which I believe if the project_id "123" doesn't exist send 0, instead of no data, but still it still showing data.

```
(count(job{branch="qa", status="failed", project_id="123"}) OR clamp_max(absent(pipeline_job_duration{project_id="123"}),0))/(count(job{branch="qa", status="success", project_id="123"})OR vector(1))
```

I want to know if there's a way for showing that there's no data with the numerator shows no data.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if there's a way for showing that there's no data with the numerator shows no data.

When two expressions are divided, they're matched by labels. Basically, if nominator returns only one time series `job=foo` and denominator returns two `job=foo` and `job=bar`, then in result you'll get only what matched `job=foo`/`job=foo`.

So I think in your case you can simply run this:

```
count(
  job{branch="qa", status="failed", project_id="123"} 
  / 
  job{branch="qa", status="success", project_id="123"}
 )
```

Comment: It is likely the proposed query will return nothing,  since all the time series on the left side of `/` contain `status="failed"` label, while all the time series on the right side contain `status="success"` label. So there are no time series pairs with identical sets of labels for the `/` operator.